# Why won't xfs_check run?

Tags: lvm

I'm running a fully updated Ubuntu 9.04 "Jaunty" i686 server. I have an single XFS volume in an LVM group called `/dev/mapper/vg0-bigthree`.

If I boot to single user mode and ensure that the volume is unmounted, I still get the following every time I try to run xfs_check:

```
$ sudo xfs_check /dev/mapper/vg0-bigthree 
xfs_check: /dev/mapper/vg0-bigthree contains a mounted and writable filesystem

fatal error -- couldn't initialize XFS library
```

Just to be thorough, I started by trying to run

```
$ sudo fsck.xfs /dev/mapper/vg0-bigthree 
If you wish to check the consistency of an XFS filesystem or
repair a damaged filesystem, see xfs_check(8) and xfs_repair(8).
```

before turning to xfs_check.

Answer (score 3):

Clearly the fs is un-mounted. It appears as though either `autofs` or `nfs` is still holding onto the file system and once they are stopped the check will run.

```
`service autofs stop`
`service nfs stop`
```

`xfs_check` is looking at stale information in `/etc/mtab` rather than up-to-date information in `/proc/mounts`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the filesystem isn't listed in /etc/mtab or /proc/mounts as mounted.  (I'm not certain which xfs_check looks for).  I've seen this occur in cases where a device wasn't cleanly unmounted.